# Need equivalent Pymongo command for for the manual working command in MongoDB prompt using array filters

Tags: mongodb, flask-pymongo

Need the Pymongo (Python Flask) equivalent command for the manual working command:

```
db.UserInfoCollection.update({ "id" : "6efb83dc365fb6bdb3b78a9a"},
                             {$set: {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},
                             {arrayFilters:[{"i.user_name":"test_user1"}, {"j.user_type": "basic"}]})
```

The above command updated the db at manual Mongodb prompt without any issues.

Tried the following (both update and update_one and arrayFilters and array_filters):

```
mongo.db.UserInfoCollection.update_one({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_name":user_name}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]}, upsert=False)
```

This command gives error when executed in Python Flask code:

```
**TypeError: update_one() got multiple values for argument 'upsert'**
mongo.db.UserInfoCollection.update_one({'id': id}, {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status':"registered"}},{"array_filters":[{"i.user_name":user_name}, {"j.user_type": user_type}]})
```

This command gives error when executed in Python Flask code:
**TypeError: upsert must be True or False**

Something is missing in my command formation in Pymongo for the working command.
Any help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pymongo you have to pass `array_filters` as a separate parameter; e.g.

```
mongo.db.UserInfoCollection.update_one({'id': id},
                                       {"$set": {'testArrayLevel1.$[i].testArrayLevel2.$[j].status': "registered"}},
                                       array_filters=[{"i.user_name": user_name}, {"j.user_type": user_type}],
                                       upsert=False)
```

Reference: [pymongo documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one)